# Editing h1 bootstrap using css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am following a tutorial to learn  bootstrap and they changed the  to be like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys5sY.jpg)

Using  Montserrat font but when I do the same changing it does not has priority over the defaults so what to do to change it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE1BP.jpg)

i use bootstrap 4

Comment: Please paste your code by editing the question. We cannot copy from the screenshot right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to style theme with class or id instead of using tag name. If this solution doesn't work you can do another thing.

```
h1{
  font-family: 'Montserrat' !important;
  font-size: 4rem !important;
  line-height: 1.5 !important;
}
```

I hope it will work

Comment: I have a question: why do we have to use" !important " in this situation?

Comment: We use !important to emphasize on that style. Because in bootstrap somewhere it is styled with h1. So when we style with our own css, it doesn't sometime.